# Spring Quartz Triggering Job programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, javabeans

I have Sprint Boot - Java 8 application that has a quartz job that I configure upon start up and set a schedule. The job runs automatically per the schedule as you would expect with a quartz job. However, now I want to be able to allow the user to manually trigger these jobs with a click of a button on the front end **WITHOUT** messing up the normal scheduling of that job. Here are all my relevant files.

`application.yml`

```
quartz:
    fooCron: 0 0 1 * * ?
    fooGroup: foo-quartz-group
```

`QuartzConfig.java`

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "quartz")
public class QuartzConfig {
    private String fooCron;
    private String fooGroup;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler() {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        Trigger[] triggers = {fooTrigger().getObject()};

        SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        quartzScheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        quartzScheduler.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
        quartzScheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
        quartzScheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        quartzScheduler.setSchedulerName("foo-scheduler");
        quartzScheduler.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        quartzScheduler.setTriggers(triggers);

        return quartzScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean fooTrigger() {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(fooJob().getObject());
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression(fooCron);
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setGroup(fooGroup);
        return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean fooJob() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setJobClass(FooJob.class);
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setGroup(fooGroup);
        jobDetailFactoryBean.setDurability(true);
        return jobDetailFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties quartzProperties() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz/quartz.properties"));
        Properties properties = null;
        try {
            propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
            properties = propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return properties;
    }

    //setters
}
```

`FooJob.java`

```
@Service
public class FooJob implements Job {
    private final FooRepository fooRepo; //This is a repository class annotated with @Repository.

    public FooJob(FooRepository fooRepo) {
        this.fooRepo = fooRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(final JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Now this runs just fun on a timed scheduled. Per the cron configuration in the yml file, `0 0 1 * * ?`, the job executes everyday at 1am. Great! But now I want to execute this manually. So I build a controller to receive manual trigger requests from the UI.

`QuartzController.java`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/quartz")
public class QuartzController {
    private SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    public DevopsController(final SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler) {
        this.schedulerFactoryBean = quartzScheduler;
        scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
    }

    @PostMapping("/execute")
    public ResponseEntity executeJob() {
        HttpStatus status = OK;
        try {
            TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey("fooTrigger", "foo-quartz-group");
            Trigger trigger = scheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey);
            ScheduleBuilder scheduleBuilder = SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(1).withRepeatCount(0);
            JobDetail jobDetail = scheduler.getJobDetail(trigger.getJobKey());
            Trigger newTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                                               .forJob(jobDetail)
                                               .startNow()
                                               .withIdentity(triggerKey)
                                               .withSchedule(scheduleBuilder)
                                               .startAt(Date.from(LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()))
                                               .build();
            //I have tried all 3 of the following lines
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(trigger)), true);
            //scheduler.addJob(jobDetail, true);
            //scheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerKey, newTrigger);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            status = BAD_REQUEST;
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(status);
    }
}
```

But everytime I run the application and hit the controller's `scheduleJob` method I get the following error in the console:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:45)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.test.jobs.FooJob
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.createJobInstance(AdaptableJobFactory.java:58)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance(SpringBeanJobFactory.java:74)
    at com.test.config.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance(AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java:27)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:41)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.jobs.FooJob.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? How do I get this job to run automatically as per schedule but also execute upon a manual request?

I am using sprint boot `1.5.9.RELEASE` and quartz `2.2.1`

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.jobs.FooJob.<init>()` Yes you do not have a no parameter constructor

Comment: @Richard is `scheduler.triggerJob(JobKey.jobKey("Your Job Key"));`  ths code not enough ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [@scary-wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) said, you have to add a no parameter constructor in `FooJob`. The problem with your approach is you won't get a `FooRepository` in that way.

```
public FooJob() {
}
```

You have 2 options

1) If `FooRepository` has a @Respository annotation, you can add a @Autowired annotation to your constructor.

```
@Autowired
public FooJob(FooRepository fooRepo) {
        this.fooRepo = fooRepo;
}
```

Thanks to you have a @Repository annotation Spring will notice that it can create an instance of the required object to create an instance of the `@service`.

2) You can add a configuration class.

```
@Configuration 
public class Config {}
```

And you have to create there an instance of your service (`FooJob`).

The first option looks better in my humble opinion.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: I know I'm late to the game but I don't understand the part below the second code example. How can I inject a different class (not a repo) properly in a class that extends Job?