# Unable newJob to instantiate Quartz job in spring

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

```
 2022-07-28 17:59:00,238 ERROR     SampleJobScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger: An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'DEFAULT.4028b8818244739301824474e92b0001'
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:47)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127)
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:392)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: vn.infoplus.infocity.infocityservice.core.job.executer.CreateNotificationFromConfigJob.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:185)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.createJobInstance(AdaptableJobFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance(SpringBeanJobFactory.java:92)
    at vn.infoplus.infocity.infocityservice.core.configuration.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance(AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java:25)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:43)
    ... 2 common frames omitted
 2022-07-28 17:59:00,264 INFO     SampleJobScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport: All triggers of Job DEFAULT.4028b8818244739301824474e92b0001 set to ERROR state.
```

I'm getting this error, but I don't know what's wrong with it yet. I spent a lot of time researching but to no avail. Does anyone have any information. Thank you for everyone

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message, but also the code itself [mcve]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the comments, I found the results here, everyone can refer [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940203/spring-quartz-triggering-job-programmatically)